# Hiding columns when using flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a web page with lots of checkboxes organised in an HTML table.  The table proves difficult for the end user to input while viewing on a mobile device.

I was pointed towards flexbox css and I've been able to lay the same table out nicely and it collapses by column for mobile viewports.

Html

```
 <h2>Responsive collapse (by column)</h2>
<div class="Rtable Rtable--2cols Rtable--collapse">

  <div style="order:0;" class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
  <div style="order:1;" class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Ice</div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="Rtable-cell">No direwolf</div>
  <div style="order:3;" class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot"><strong>Lord of Winterfell</strong></div>

  <div style="order:0;" class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
  <div style="order:1;" class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Longclaw</div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>
  <div style="order:3;" class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot"><strong>Knows nothing</strong></div>

</div>

<h2>Responsive collapse (by row)</h2>
<div class="Rtable Rtable--4cols Rtable--collapse">

  <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Ice</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell">No direwolf</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot"><strong>Lord of Winterfell</strong></div>

  <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--head"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell">Has a sword named Longclaw</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>
  <div class="Rtable-cell Rtable-cell--foot"><strong>Knows nothing</strong></div>

</div>
```

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/KzWORB)

My question is I'm trying to hide some columns depending on a users input.  I have 6 columns per page and don't always want to show them all. I'm using jquery to do this.  When hiding a column it distorts the whole view even when altering the class for the total amount of columns after hiding.

Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: Where's your jquery?

Comment: Sorry I'm typing this off my mobile and copied the example I used.

Comment: I gave each column a class and used $('.class').hide();

Comment: Even tried wrapping each column and trying to hide it that way, but even that distorts the whole table